# error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy tratando de emular mi app pero me encuentro con este tipo de problemas:

> mLastLocation= FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
>       FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
>     FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

tengo estos tres errores que no he podido resolver por favor ayuda

Comment: Ya pasó cierto tiempo, pero si te sirve el dato. Este error se da cuando las versiones de Firebase y las de Play Services son dispares entre sí.
Como referencia: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/439#issuecomment-265008493

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has definido la dependencia de `Firebase` necesaria dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, define como minimo la versión 17.0.1, en mi caso yo uso la versión 21.1.0 :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'   
    ...
    ...
}
```